# if textfield does not contain email address make stripe button show alert on click

Tags: jquery

I have a stripe button on my page that allows users to pay for a product through stripe.

I basically want to only enable the button to work when the email address field contains a valid email address. At the moment it validates correctly, however I am wondering how to make it so if you click on the button when no email address or an incorrect valid address is entered it shows an alert. If the validation is right then the stripe button will work as normal.

**STRIPE BUTTON**

```
<script id="stripe-script"
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-email="<?echo $invited->email;?>"
data-key="<?= get_option('stripe_public') ?>"
data-description= "<?echo $host->host;?> - <?echo $brunch->name;?> - <?echo $brunch->shortlocation;?>";
data-image="<? if ($imagefound1 > "0"){echo $imagedeets->att_file;}else{echo"/mainsite/images/listing-item-02.jpg";}?>"
data-locale="auto"
data-zip-code="false"
data-currency="<?= get_option('currency_code') ?>">
</script>
```

**MY PAGE**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <label>Email Address </label>
<input type="email" name = "email" id="booking-email" value="<?echo $invited->email;?>"  <? if ($invited->email != ""){echo "disabled";?> style="background-color: #e3e3e3;" <?}?> />
</div>
```

**EMAIL VALIDATION**

```
  var validateEmail = function(elementValue) {
                var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
                return emailPattern.test(elementValue);
            }



            $('#booking-email').keyup(function() {

                var value = $(this).val();
                var valid = validateEmail(value);

                if (!valid) {


                    $(this).css('color', 'red');
 //STOP BUTTON FROM LOADING CC FORM (STRIPES POPUP)
                } else {


                    $(this).css('color', '#000');
// ENABLE STRIPE BUTTON TO WORK 
                }



            });
```

Comment: Is the button part of a `<form>`? If so, show the form.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
var validateEmail = function(elementValue) {
                var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
                return emailPattern.test(elementValue);
            }



            $('#booking-email').keyup(function() {

                var value = $(this).val();
                var valid = validateEmail(value);

                if (!valid) {


                    $(this).css('color', 'red');
 //STOP BUTTON FROM LOADING CC FORM (STRIPES POPUP)
 $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
                } else {


                    $(this).css('color', '#000');
// ENABLE STRIPE BUTTON TO WORK 
$('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
                }



            });
$("#submit").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault;
if(validateEmail($('#booking-email').val())) alert('valid'); else alert('not valid');
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <label>Email Address </label>
<input type="email" name = "email" id="booking-email" value=""/>
</div>
<button id="submit" disabled>submit</button>
```

Comment: I tried disabled, however its not exactly what i am looking for. I need an alert to show up when the button is clicked.